# How to get the sum of values in selected rows in a QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Am having a Python program designed with PyQt where i use a QTableView to display data from a database. Am using the program to find specified matching values and then select them. After the items being highlighted, i want to be able to find the sum of the selected values in a specified column. Here is my code that am trying to use.

```
start = self.table_model2.index(0, 4)
matches = self.table_model2.match(start, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, code, -1, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)

for index in matches:
    self.tableView2.selectionModel().select(index, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select |
                                                QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Rows)

for index in sorted(self.tableView2.selectionModel().selectedRows()):
    row = index.row()
    self.payment = self.table_model2.data(self.table_model2.index(row, 9))
    print(sum([int(self.payment)]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting to whole, then to a list and finally you add that unnecessary list, the last 2 tasks are unnecessary, the correct thing is to accumulate the values:

```
result = 0
for index in sorted(self.tableView2.selectionModel().selectedRows()):
    payment = self.table_model2.data(self.table_model2.index(index.row(), 9))
    result += int(payment)
print(result)
```